# Adjust iframe height automatically according to page-content : height varying with search result from same page

Tags: iframe

Initially the following page has a fixed height with a form:
http://arms.aero/gmg/ftrack/ftrack.aspx
when search is done the height of this page varies according to the reach-result.

Now I have to display this page as inner content from another page (its a php page)  – so that the varying heights adjust automatically according to its page content.

I have tried with an iframe feature like this http://host.sonspring.com/iframe/ .
But the problem is - it is using different pages to adjust iframe heights, and mine is only one page (initial content and content with search result).

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: sample code:
<iframe src="http://arms.aero/gmg/ftrack/ftrack.aspx" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can change for even when you want.

> $('#iframe').live('mousemove', function (event) {
>
> var theFrame = $(this, parent.document.body);
>
> this.height($(document.body).height() - 350);
> });